# Save value from the drop down menu into database (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that shows categories from the database (table `category`, with two columns: `category_id` and `category_name`). The second table is `photo`s and it has a foreign key `category_id`.

Code that shows drop-down menu from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM category";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='category_name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['category_name'] . "'>" . $row['category_name'] . "</option>"; }

echo "</select>";
```

Now I don't know how to save the chosen option of category in the database. Any help appreciated ...

Comment: On form post, use `$_POST['category_name']` to get the value and then do a `INSERT INTO photos ....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's heavy :D

(1) you will need to enclose the select element in a form (a form is an HTML element that holds data and can be submitted entirely to the server, know more about forms here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

```html
<form action='x.php' method='post'>
  <select .....
</form>
```

where **x** is the path of the php file in which we will will carry out the necessary processing to save our data

(2) optional step - you will also need to set the value of each option to the id of the category instead of it's name

```html
echo "<option value='{$row['category_id']}'>{$row['category_name']}</option>";
```

(3) now in x.php, we need to read the field value and store it in the DB

```html
<?php 
  $value = $_POST['category_name'];
  // $value now stores the selected category
?>
```

All you have to do now is to store the value in the database using the my sql query function

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it. Can I use the same file for the action (action = '') or does it have to be the other file (action = 'x.php')?

Comment: you can use any file, if you didn't specify the action or you set it to an empty string (action='') => the default action will be the current file, but in this case we need to make an extra condition. There are 2 situations: the 1st is when you run the file for the first time ==> in this situation there is nothing to save and $value is empty, the 2nd is when the data is submitted to the current file and here we need to store the data not to show the select, a simple if condition can fullfill this <?php if(isset($_POST['category_name'])) {//read value and store it} else {// show the select}?>

Comment: try it, if you still have a problem you can comment !

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['category_name'] 
     . "'>" . $row['category_name'] . "</option>";
```

You write category_name in the value of the option field, but you probably want to use category_id here.

After the user submits you can get the category id with `$_POST['category_name']`.
That is because your form has the name *category_name*, you might want to change the form name to *category_id* also.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can change the select name to 'category_id' and the option value to 'category_id' (since this is the value you will be saving in the db).  You then need to wrap your select options in a form tag.  Your form method will be "post" and the action could be something like save_category.php.  In your save_category.php you need to collect the post as follows `$_POST['category_id']` and insert into the database with a query in a similar manner to how you extracted the category_id and category_name.